# newly installed stack not yet working - what did I miss?

Tags: ros, installation, stack

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone

I'm trying to get a newly installed stack to work, it's my first time so be gentle :).
The package I would like to install is [gpsd_client](http://www.ros.org/wiki/gpsd_client).
So I used following command, with the stack name found [here](http://www.ros.org/wiki/umd-ros-pkg)

sudo apt-get install ros-unstable-gps-umd

and this seems to run through properly. If I run it again it says "ros-unstable-gps-umd is already the newest version", so that sound good.
If I then run

rosrun gpsd_client gpsd_client _host:=localhost _port:=2947

I get the error "[rospack] couldn't find package [gpsd_client]". What did I miss? And where did the installed files go? Intuitively I would expect to /opt/ros/releasename/stacks ... but there I dont find it.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10106/newly-installed-stack-not-yet-working---what-did-i-miss?/) by [tschoni](https://answers.ros.org/users/618/tschoni/) on ROS Answers with karma: 18 on 2011-05-29

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ivan Dryanovski](https://answers.ros.org/users/79/ivan-dryanovski/) on 2011-05-29**:
Which version of ROS did you install - unstable or diamondback? If you installed unstable, everything should be in /opt/ros/unstable/stacks. If you installed diamondback, you should probably use ros-diamondback-gps-umd instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have diamondback installed but didn't understand that "unstable" is referred to the ROS version. Now that I know this is trivial.

ros-diamondback-gps-umd

did the trick.
Thanks a lot, Dryanovski

---

Which version of ROS did you install - unstable or diamondback? If you installed unstable, everything should be in /opt/ros/unstable/stacks. If you installed diamondback, you should probably use ros-diamondback-gps-umd instead. - Ivan Dryanovski (13 hours ago)

---

Originally posted by [tschoni](https://answers.ros.org/users/618/tschoni/) with karma: 18 on 2011-05-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0